# How to show multiple notifications in Foreground Service?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I'm making a note app that has an option for pinning notes in the notifications.
I'm using foreground service but the problem is when I want to pin more than one note, the notification for the second one replaces the first one.
I'm using each note's unique ID as `notificationId`. Here's my code :

```
    class MyService : Service() {

    lateinit var note: Note

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
    }


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        note = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_EXTRA)!!
        showNotification()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(note.noteText)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setGroup(CHANNEL_GROUP_KEY)
            .build()

        startForeground(note.id, notification)

    }


    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually why a service for that? Why not simply show the notification and cancel it from dismissing

Comment: @Sambhav.K Well I don't want the notification get dismissed when user clears all notifications or just swipes it. It's like a reminder that only gets dismissed if you press the done button or something...

Comment: ok. I can give a answers for that thing. U want me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by using
startForeground(notifyId.toInt(), notificationBuilder) in onCreate method of service and then in onStartCommand use
notificationManager.notify(notifyId.toInt(), notificationBuilder);

Basically you need to only use startForeground once and then you need to use notification manager for showing notification. That way you are able to show all the notifications and all are using foreground service